# Is there anyway to create a chart in Laravel without having to use routes and controllers?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, charts

Any option I find for using charts in laravel and laravel wrappers use routing and controllers, which would make trying to display the data I'm trying to represent in the graph very hard to push through to the controller.

I've tried using chart js using Vue but it is not working, any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply open a blade and use #javascript inside to show chart this is s simple file with some fake data you can try it just copy all and pate in a blade (DONT FORGET TO ADD @extend('') AT THE TOP:

```
@section('content')
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="box box-primary">
<div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title">Area Chart</h3>

    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="chart">
        <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
var myChart1 = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext('2d');

// Global Options
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';

var massPopChart = new Chart(myChart1, {
  type:'bar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
  data:{
    labels:['Boston', 'Worcester', 'Springfield', 'Lowell', 'Cambridge', 'New Bedford'],
    datasets:[{
      label:'Population',
      data:[
        617594,
        181045,
        153060,
        106519,
        105162,
        95072
      ],
      //backgroundColor:'green',
      backgroundColor:[
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
      ],
      borderWidth:1,
      borderColor:'#777',
      hoverBorderWidth:3,
      hoverBorderColor:'#000'
    }]
  },
  options:{
    title:{
      display:true,
      text:'Largest Cities In Massachusetts',
      fontSize:25,
      responsive: true
    },
    legend:{
      display:true,
      position:'right',
      labels:{
        fontColor:'#000'
      }
    },
    layout:{
      padding:{
        left:50,
        right:0,
        bottom:0,
        top:0
      }
    },
    tooltips:{
      enabled:true
    }



  }
});


  </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: @a bcd perfect that could work, I'm using PHP to fill in the data in a for each loop iterating through a data set, I havent used javascript before how would I go injecting my data into there? Thanks!

Comment: you can put your data on date base with json format and then get your data and show un the chart